# select query for multiple checkboxes?

Tags: apex, soql, community

VF Page

```
<apex:page Controller="actionSupportController">
   <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock >
            Household Name: <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}"/>          
           </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Characteristics Information">

        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Active_c}" />Active<br/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Good_with_Cats_c}" />Good with Cats<br/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.HighNeed__c}" />HighNeed<br/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.kid_friendly__c}" />Kid Friendly<br/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.Non_shedder__c}" />Non Shedder<br/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.Predatory_Tendencies__c}" />Prediator Tendency<br/>

       <br/><apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!dochar}" rerender="sblck"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel id="sblck">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results">
    <apex:pageBlockTable width="80%" value="{!selctchr}" var="eachpe">
        <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Name}"/>
         <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Gender__c}"/>
        <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Height__c}"/>       
        <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.pet__c}"/>
        <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c}"/>
        <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Status__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
       <apex:commandButton value="Request Adoption"/>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class actionSupportController {
    public List<PCS_Household__c> lstQuery{get;set;} 
    public List<PCS_Household__c> OnlstQuery{get;set;}
    public List<Characteristics__c> selctchr{get;set;}
    public Characteristics__c sct{get;set;}
    public string ID_c{get;set;}      
    public string test{get;set;}
    public string Good_with_Cats_c{get;set;}    
    public string Active_c{get;set;}
    public List<Pets_Information__c> selctpet{get;set;}

    Public Boolean Good{get;set;}



    public void dochar(){
        string query='';
        system.debug('==sct.Good_with_Cats_c=='+Good_with_Cats_c);
        query='**SELECT Name,ID,Good_with_Cats__c,Pet_ID__r.Gender__c,Pet_ID__r.Height__c,Pet_ID__r.Name__c,Pet_ID__r.pet__c,Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c,Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c where Good_with_Cats__c='+Good_with_Cats_c or +Active_c**;

        system.debug('==query=='+query);
        selctchr=Database.query(query);    
        system.debug('==selctchr=='+selctchr);
    }


    public PageReference incrementCounter() {
       string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID=:test';        
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        OnlstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==OnlstQuery=='+OnlstQuery);
        return null;
    }

     public Void doSearch(){
        string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%'+ID_c+'%\'';
         system.debug('==ID_c=='+ID_c);
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);
    }

    public void nullify(){
        lstQuery.clear();
    }

    public PageReference nextpage() {

        upsert OnlstQuery;

        return Page.cc;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details on what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: i am getting this error "expecting a semi-colon, found 'or'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel below corrected version of query will work for you:

```
query='SELECT Name,ID,Good_with_Cats__c,Pet_ID__r.Gender__c,Pet_ID__r.Height__c,Pet_ID__r.Name__c,Pet_ID__r.pet__c,Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c,Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c where Good_with_Cats__c=\''+Good_with_Cats_c+'\' or Active__c=\''+Active_c+'\'';
```